# Redmine on Redhat/CentOS 5 Without using virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, redmine

I've have followed all the steps to install Redmine on CentOS 5, except for the Apache part:

> http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_Redmine_on_CentOS_5

I do not want to configure a virtualhost as we are not using virtual hosts.

Can I configure Redmine to run with `http://hostname/redmine`?

Apparently it doesn't work for my case.

Redmine was extracted in to the webserver document root /var/www/html/ called /var/www/html/redmine

What I did was added a `redmine.conf` to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` with the following configuration and restarted the server:

```
<Location "/redmine">
    Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all

    PassengerEnabled On
    RailsBaseURI /var/www/html/redmine
    RailsEnv production
</Location>
```

now i got this error

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
    No such file or directory - config/environment.rb
Exception class:
    Errno::ENOENT
Application root:
    /var/www/html

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To suppress directory listings remove the `Indexes` option from your `Options` list.

Answer (score 0):

RailsBaseURI is wrong, It should be this

```
RailsBaseURI /var/www/html/redmine/public
```

Comment: Ammended it, restart httpd, but i'm still getting the folder list ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine. I use a symlink for redmine at /var/www/html/redmine .

```
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
RailsBaseURI /redmine
<Directory /var/www/html/redmine>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    PassengerUser redmine
    PassengerGroup redmine
</Directory>

<Location /redmine/sys>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Deny from all
</Location>
```